# Compatibility of conditional and marginal independence assumptions

Tags: independence, conditional-independence

I want to know if two independence assumptions, as illustrated below, would go together or not.

Consider I have 4 variables, A,B,C,D. Can the following two independence assumptions co-exist?

$A \perp B | C,D$ and $(A,C) \perp D$ ?

Comment: In term of pdf (probability density function) what do that two things mean?

Comment: how about a <- c -> b <- d